# Error implementing relational model in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[MER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFNb9.png)

I need help creating this MER in Oracle. Specifically in FOTOS table as I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE "FOTOS"
(  
    "ID_FOTO" INT NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID_USU" INT NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "FECHA" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT "FOTOS_PK" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("ID_FOTO") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FOTOS_FK" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("ID_USU") REFERENCES "USUARIOS" ("ID_USU") ENABLE
)
```

However I keep getting this error:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

ID_USU is one of two primary keys in USUARIOS
[USUARIOS TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28dcT.png)

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: If you get an `ORA-xxxx` error - then you're ***NOT*** using (Microsoft) SQL Server - fixed tags and title accordingly

Comment: Your title and tags say SQL Server, but that error is clearly from Oracle, and that syntax is *not* valid T-SQL.

Comment: Yes, im actually using Oracle APEX 11g

Comment: Please learn to tag correctly in the future, @QUIQUE . Mistagging can lead to your question be closed as unclear, or at least delays you in getting the attention of users that can answer your question.

Comment: Looks like "ID_USU" column doesn't have unique values in the table "USUARIOS". Create the column "ID_USU" as primary key.

Comment: @Roshan its a primary key of the two ive marked in USUARIOS

Comment: @Larnu sorry im new :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

> ID_USU is one of two primary keys in USUARIOS

No. A table can have just one primary key. It can have more than one unique key, but you can only make one of them primary.

What you mistakenly did instead is create a composite primary key. You want the ID to be unique and the name to be unique, but instead you made the combination of ID and name unique, thus allowing duplicate IDs and duplicate names in the table.

What you have:

```
create table usuarios
(
  id_usu  number        not null,
  nomusu  varchar2(50)  not null,
  ...
  constraint pk_usuarios primary key (id_usu, nomusu)
);
```

What you want instead:

```
create table usuarios
(
  id_usu  number        not null,
  nomusu  varchar2(50)  not null,
  ...
  constraint pk_usuarios primary key (id_usu),
  constraint uq_usuarios_nomusu unique (nomusu)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys have to match the primary/unique key they reference column for column. Since the primary key of "USUARIOS" are columns "ID_USU" and "NOMUSU" you need two columns to add FK from "FOTOS" to "USUARIOS", so just add "NOMUSU" column to "FOTOS" and write:

```
    CREATE TABLE "FOTOS"
    (  
    "ID_FOTO" INT NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID_USU" INT NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "NOMUSU" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "FECHA" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT "FOTOS_PK" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("ID_FOTO") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FOTOS_FK" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("ID_USU","NOMUSU") REFERENCES "USUARIOS" ("ID_USU","NOMUSU") ENABLE);
```